# How to create desktop application using Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, desktop-application

Is it possible to create Desktop(Windows OS) application using Angular 2?

If yes then how can we build setup for desktop? Will it support windows 7 and Earlier?

I noticed that, Angular 2 is for cross platform.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try using Electron (by GitHub): http://electron.atom.io/

Here an example using Electron + Angular 2: https://auth0.com/blog/2015/12/15/create-a-desktop-app-with-angular-2-and-electron/

Comment: Keeweb is an example that demonstrates how an electron application could look like: https://keeweb.info/
It is also opensource and available on github

Comment: Electron is your best bet for cross platform. But if you only need to support Windows you can create an Angular2 Universal Windows App https://github.com/preboot/angular2-universal-windows-app

Comment: @Sergio Rodrigues Can we create desktop application using angular2 and python?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a **Medium** post about that [here](https://medium.com/@en.ahmed.mk/build-desktop-apps-with-the-power-of-angular-1e44d13d77a4), and here's an [example](https://medium.com/@en.ahmed.mk/build-desktop-apps-with-the-power-of-angular-1e44d13d77a4), happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 options

1) Node web Kit - [NWJS](https://nwjs.io/)

2) ElectronJS - [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)

Both are helps to develop Cross Platform Application
combination of `NodeJS+Chromium Browser`  can support 3rd parties libraies.. so you develop web app like Desktop using these 2 for all 3 platforms(Linux, Mac, Windows)